# Lodash throttle not working correctly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash, throttling

I have a function that filters through some state and renders out the result for a search request.

```
  const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
   const searchResultData = users.filter((userId) => user.id.startsWith(value));
   setSearchResult(searchResultData);
  };
```

I am trying to work with `lodash.throttle` library to cause a delay before the request is sent. So we don't have a request go out every time a user types.

```
 const handleSearch = useCallback(throttle((value: string) => {
  const searchResultData = users.filter((userId) => user.id.startsWith(value));
  setSearchResult(searchResultData);
 }, 2500), []);
```

This works in delaying input as expected but for some reason, the `user.filter` method doesn't run, and so the state isn't updated with the search result. I believe the problem might be from the `useCallback` hook, but the `throttle` function is dependent on it to run. Any ideas on how I can work around this problem?

Comment: Should `useCallback` have `users` as a dependency?  It might be that you're closing over `users` when you first define the callback and so subsequent calls have the "initial" user list which might be empty?  Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

If your throttled/debounced handler uses props or state, like this:

```
const { fetcherFunctionFromProps } = props;

const eventHandler = async () => {
  const resp = await fetcherFunctionFromProps();
};    

const debouncedEventHandler = useMemo(
  () => throttle(eventHandler, 300)
), [fetcherFunctionFromProps]);
```

And it doesn't work,
you can refactor it to the following:

```
const { fetcherFunctionFromProps } = props;

const eventHandler = async (fetcher) => {
  const resp = await fetcher();
};

const debouncedEventHandler = useMemo(() => throttle(eventHandler, 300), []);
...
<Component onClick={() => debouncedEventHandler(fetcherFunctionFromProps)}>
```